# Excel to MySQL Data manipulation

Tags: mysql, excel

Newbie in SQL and need some help transforming some data from Excel into a SQL table. I have the following table setup in Excel.

[image]

Each instrument is unqiue but I need the data to be put into a table such that it is a timeseries per instrument e.g.:

[image]

The Excel column heading is seperated by a comma but I could change that to anything that works better.

Thanks for the help.
Cheers

Comment: Are there always 4 nodes/tokens in the column headers?

Comment: Yes, will all be the same  @P.Salmon